# python lxml.html add parameter

Tags: python, html, lxml

I have a html-template where i want to add some content. The Template looks like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Data Base</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Data Base</h1>
    <div class="file_explorer">
    </div>
    <div class="info_screen">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to search for the `<div class="file_explorer"></div>` and add some parameters to it. Afterwards it should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Data Base</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Data Base</h1>
    <div class="file_explorer">
        <p class="folder">Folder_1</p>
        <p class="folder">Folder_2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info_screen">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Therefore I tried to parse the html-template and wanted to search for the file_explorer tag to add the paragraphs. How do I search for them and add the paragraphs afterwards. I tried html.cssselector but it did not work. Pls help me. Thats my code:

```
from lxml import html
from os import path

class HtmlGenerator:

@staticmethod
def modify_html(html_path, list_folders):
    html_path = path.abspath(html_path)
    parser = html.HTMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
    if path.isfile(html_path) and html_path.endswith(".html"):
        tree = html.parse(html_path, parser)
        # search for <div class="file_explorer"> [MISSING]
        for folder in list_folders:
            # add folder as paragraph to html [MISSING]
        tree.write(html_path, pretty_print=True)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath to find the target `div` in your template, and then use [E-factory](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#creating-html-with-the-e-factory) to build the new elements :

```
from lxml.html import builder as E
....
tree = html.parse(html_path, parser)
root = tree.getroot()
# search for <div class="file_explorer">
div = root.find('.//div[@class="file_explorer"]')
for folder in list_folders:
    # add folder as paragraph to html
    # I assume `folder` as a string like 'Folder_1', 'Folder_2', ...
    d.append(E.P(E.CLASS('folder'), folder))
tree.write(html_path, pretty_print=True)
```

Comment: Thanks it works well and gets displayed in the browser correctly. Its just not very nice formatted because all paragraphs which has been added automatically are in the same line than the <div> tag. But i thought pretty print does care about that. Any Idea?

Comment: I do also have another question concerning the topic. How do I add multiple attributes to the paragraph. I am asking because I want to have a class attribute and an ID attribute. Writting **d.append(E.P(E.CLASS('folder'), id='1', folder))** did not work.

Comment: I don't know about how to make the result nicely formatted, but regarding parameters for additional attributes such as `id`, they should come after paragraph's content parameter : `E.P(E.CLASS('folder'), folder, id='1')`

Comment: I have found out that it does work too if you write all attributes inside a dictionary like this: `E.P({'class': 'folder', 'id': '1'}, folder)`. Formatting should have worked because I used Pretty Print but it does not. Hope someone else does have an idea but its just a minor problem.